# PHP Redirect Header with a Variable

Tags: php

I have a php script that updates a mysql database. Once its done, I want to redirect back to the details page. I know that this can be done in a header redirect, but I can't get it to add the variable to the address. My code that I have is below.

```
<?php
include "../config.php";
$_GET["hiveid"] = $HiveID;
$_GET["hivename"] = $HiveName;
$_GET["hiveloca"] = $HiveLoca;
mysql_query("UPDATE hives SET HiveName='$HiveName', LocationID='$HiveLoca' WHERE    HiveID='$HiveID'") or die (mysql_error()); 
$URL = "../hivedetails.php?HiveID=" . $HiveID;
header("Location: " . $URL);
?>
```

Comment: Which variable you want to add? `$_GET`?

Comment: Your variable assignment seems to be the wrong way around. Shouldn't it be `$HiveID = $_GET["hiveid"];` ?

Comment: dont you want `$HiveID=$_GET["hiveid"];` ? not that there's any point simply creating new variables.

Comment: yep...This is what you have to do.. $HiveID=$_GET["hiveid"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. STOP WORKING ON THIS CODE and read up about [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com). Your code is just begging for your server to get pwn3d
2. Learn basic PHP syntax. You're assigning your variables backwards. `$HiveID = $_GET['hiveid']` is what you want, and similarly for the other two lines
3. Your actual problem will go away once you fix #2.

Comment: I have not thought about the SQL injections and I will be definitely be reading up on this more. I have switched around all of my codes and I also realized that I made a huge (newbie) mistake. I used POST in my form, not GET. Thanks again for your help and advise.